# How to include flag icons in vuetify's v-select?

Tags: vue.js, web, frontend, vuetify.js

I have this normal v-select

```
        <v-select
          v-model="selected"
          class="ml-2 pl-2"
          :items="lang"
          variant="plain"
          density="compact"
          prepend-icon="mdi-web"
          
        >
      </v-select>
```

I am trying to switch between the languages with
`lang: ['English', 'French','arabic'],`
I want to include flag icons **inside the v-select** and tried implementing [flag-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flag-icons)
but i noticed that i can no longer choose / click on the v-select items
How do I include the icons(or images) so the v-select include them inside it's items and show the selected item with it's icon ?

Tried something like this

```
<v-select
    class="ml-2 pl-2"
    :items="lang"
    variant="plain"
    density="compact"
  >
    <template #item="{ item }">
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-icon>{{ getIconForLanguage(item) }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-content>
          {{ item }}
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

with

```
data() {
    return {
      lang: ['English', 'French']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getIconForLanguage(language) {
      return language === 'English' ? 'mdi-translate' : 'mdi-menu-down';
    }
```

just to test it on normal icons but still can't use the v-select

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using v-list-item-content, I assume this is Vuetify 2, right?

In Vuetify 2, the [`#item`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots) slot has two slot props, `on` and `attrs`, which contain listeners and attributes that you need to bind to the v-list-item:

```html
<template #item="{ item, on, attrs }">
  <v-list-item v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
    ...
  </v-list-item>
</template>
```

Here is a snippet where your example is working:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
            
          <v-select
            v-model="language"
            class="ml-2 pl-2"
            :items="languageOption"
            variant="outlined"
            density="compact"
            prepend-icon="mdi-web"
          >
            <template #item="{ item, on, attrs }">
              <v-list-item v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
                <v-list-item-avatar>
                  <v-icon>{{ getIconForLanguage(item) }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-list-item-content> {{ item }} </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </template>
          </v-select>
      
          <pre>language: {{language}}</pre>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  `,
    data() {
      return {
        language: 'arabic',
        languageOption: ['English', 'French', 'arabic'],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getIconForLanguage(language) {
        return language === 'English' ? 'mdi-translate' : 'mdi-menu-down';
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: actually it's vuetify 3 but i fixed it with a simple v-if
<v-img v-if="item.raw.name=='English'" src="../assets/lang/gb.png" /> 
<v-img v-else src="../assets/lang/fr.png" />

Comment: Are you sure? There is no v-list-item-content in v3, using it should give you a warning. Also, I don't understand how a `v-if` fixes the problem of missing handlers, which I think is what you were asking? In v3, you have to use `props` instead of `on` and `attrs`.

Comment: ye appearently  i was using the wrong documentation so i removed all the vuetify 2 code
my problem was solved by just using `v-if` and calling the 2 options without using methods / nor sending a language list from the data since i only needed 2 languages